# how to use if not exists while inserting a row mysql

Tags: mysql

The thing that i want to do is to check if there is a same row and if not to insert a new row to the table.

In that case, how can i use `if not exists` ?

```
INSERT INTO `facebook` (`ID`,`fb_id`,`label_id`,`page_ids`,`token`) VALUES (NULL,'". $session['id'] ."','$id','','". $access_token ."')
```

For example, in that query, i want to check if there is a row with the same label_id record and if not, execute that query.

any help ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` syntax. When using this, duplicate key errors are treated as warnings and the statement will return without having inserted the affected row.

Comment: Make sure you have a unique index, or primary key on `label_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `facebook` (`ID`,`fb_id`,`label_id`,`page_ids`,`token`) 
SELECT NULL, '". $session['id'] ."', '$id', '', '". $access_token ."'
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM facebook WHERE label_id = '$id')
```

I think `FROM DUAL` is optional, but I'm an Oracle guy. :)

Answer (score 0):

User Insert Into to ignore duplicates:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `facebook`
SET `ID` = null,
`fb_id` = '". $session['id'] ."',
`label_id` = '$id',
`page_ids`='',
`token`='". $access_token ."';
```