# MySQL, inserting row if not exists

Tags: mysql, transactions, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use if not exists while inserting a row mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930615/how-to-use-if-not-exists-while-inserting-a-row-mysql)

I have problem:

I have table named "table" with 4 columns: id(int, PK, AI, Unique), col1(varchar), col2(varchar), col3(datetime)

Many users can connect to mysql server and insert rows into "table". The problem is that col2 and col3 can't exists in other row in "table".

I would write something like that:
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from table where col2='2' and col3='2012-12-12 12:12:12') INSERT INTO table(col1, col2, col3) values(1,2,'2012-12-12 12:12:12')

I assume you know what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to do this in one statement (to avoid situation in which 2 users inserts the same row at the same time) or in transaction. If I should do it in transaction, then what type of isolation should it be? Serializable isolation causes lock tables so it can slow down inserting process much more. 
Help me, please.

Comment: But it's not what i'm talking about.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492761/performing-an-update-or-insert-depending-whether-a-row-exists-or-not-in-mysql and there are several others. One of our most frequently recurring questions. If it's not the same, make clear how.

Comment: col2 and col3 can't be unique. col2 OR col3 can be duplicated. I can't duplicate col2 AND(!!!) col3 if the same 2 columns EXISTS in ONE ROW!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want duplicates for the pair of col2 and col3 (i.e. col 2 can have duplicates but any pair of col2 and col3 only appears once) you can specify this:

```
UNIQUE(col2,col3)
```

Any query which now attempts to insert a col2,col3 pair will fail. You can deal with this either using:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table(col1, col2, col3) values(1,2,'2012-12-12 12:12:12');
```

or if the insert should change the values you can use:

```
INSERT INTO table(col1, col2, col3) values(1,2,'2012-12-12 12:12:12') 
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE someCol=someVal
```